# Sum different date intervals year over year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a number of stores where I would like to sum the energy consumption so far this year compared with the same period last year. My challenge is that in the current year the stores have different date intervals in terms of delivered data. That means that store A may have data between 01.01.2018 and 20.01.2018, and store B may have data between 01.01.2018 and 28.01.2018. I would like to sum the same date intervals current year versus previous year.

Data looks like this

```
Store   Date    Sum
A   01.01.2018  12
A   20.01.2018  11
B   01.01.2018  33
B   28.01.2018  32
```

But millions of rows and would use these dates as references to get the same sums previous year.

This is my (erroneous) try:

```
SET @curryear = (SELECT YEAR(MAX(start_date)) FROM energy_data);
SET @maxdate_curryear = (SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM energy_data WHERE 
YEAR(start_date) = @curryear);
SET @mindate_curryear = (SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM energy_data WHERE 
YEAR(start_date) = @curryear);

-- the same date intervals last year

SET @maxdate_prevyear = (@maxdate_curryear - INTERVAL 1 YEAR); 
SET @mindate_prevyear = (@mindate_curryear - INTERVAL 1 YEAR); 

-- sums current year

CREATE TABLE t_sum_curr AS
SELECT name as name_curr, sum(kwh) as sum_curr, min(start_date) AS 
min_date_curr, max(start_date) AS max_date_curr, count(distinct 
start_date) AS ant_timer FROM energy_data WHERE agg_type = 'timesnivå' 
AND start_date >= @mindate_curryear and start_date <= @maxdate_curryear GROUP BY NAME; 

-- also seems fair, the same dates one year ago, figured I should find those first and in the next query use that to sum each stores between those date intervals

CREATE TABLE t_sum_prev AS
SELECT name_curr as name_curr2, (min_date_curr - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS 
min_date_prev, (max_date_curr - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) as max_date_prev FROM 
t_sum_curr;

-- getting into trouble!

CREATE TABLE the_results AS
SELECT name, start_date, sum(kwh) as sum_prev from energy_data where 
agg_type = 'timesnivå' and
            start_date >= @mindate_prevyear and start_date <= 
@maxdate_prevyear group by name having start_date BETWEEN (SELECT 
min_date_prev from t_sum_prev) AND                                                                      
(SELECT max_date_prev from t_sum_prev);
```

`
This last query just tells me that my sub query returns more than 1 row and throws an error message.

Comment: Can you show the table structure and sample data along with DDL scripts? Will be easier to get you a working solution with all of that present.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you have is a list of energy consumption figures, where bills or readings have been taken at irregular times, so the consumption covers irregular periods.

The basic approach you need to take is to regularise the consumption periods - by establishing which days each periods covers, and then breaking each reading down into as many days as it covers, and the consumption for each day being a daily average of the period.

I'm assuming the consumption periods are entirely sequential (as a bill or reading normally would be), and not overlapping.

Because of the volume of rows involved (you say millions even in its current form), you might not want to leave the data in daily form - it might suffice to regroup them into regular weekly, monthly, or quarterly periods, depending on what level of granularity you require for comparison.

Once you have your regular periods, comparison will be as easy as cake.

If this is part of a report that will be run on an ongoing basis, you'd probably want to implement some logic that calculates a "regularised consumption" incrementally and on a scheduled basis and stores it in a summary table, with appropriate columns and indexes, so that you aren't having to process many millions of historical rows each time the report is run.

Trying to work around the irregular periods (if indeed it can be done) with fancy joins and on-the-fly averages, rather than tackling them head on, will likely lead to very difficult logic, and particularly on a data set of this size, dire performance.

**EDIT:** from the comments below.

@Alexander, I've knocked together an example of a query. I haven't tested it and I've written it all in a text editor, so excuse any small syntax errors. What I've come up with seems a bit complex (more complex than I imagined when I began), but I'm also a little bit tired, so I'm not sure whether it could be simplified further.

The only point I would make is that the performance of this query (or any such query), because of the nature of what it has to do in traversing date ranges, is likely to be appalling on a table with millions of rows. I stand by my earlier remarks, that proper indexing of the source data will be crucial, and summarising the source data into a larger granularity will massively aid performance (at the expense of a one-off hit to summarise it). Even daily granularity, will reduce the number of rows by a factor of 24!

```
WITH energy_data_ext AS
(
    SELECT
        ed.name                 AS store_name
        ,YEAR(ed.start_date)    AS reading_year
        ,ed.start_date          AS reading_date
        ,ed.kwh                 AS reading_kwh
    FROM
        energy_data AS ed
)

,available_stores AS
(
    SELECT ede.store_name
    FROM energy_data_ext AS ede
    GROUP BY ede.store_name
)

,current_reading_yr_per_store AS
(
    SELECT
        ede.store_name
        ,MAX(ede.reading_year)  AS current_reading_year
    FROM
        energy_data_ext AS ede
    GROUP BY 
        ede.store_name
)

,latest_reading_ranges_per_year AS
(
    SELECT
        ede.store_name
        ,ede.reading_year
        ,MAX(ede.start_date) AS latest_reading_date_of_yr
    FROM
        energy_data_ext AS ede
    GROUP BY
        ede.store_name
        ,ede.reading_year
)

,store_reading_ranges AS
(
    SELECT
        avs.store_name
        ,lryps.current_reading_year
        ,lyrr.latest_reading_date_of_yr AS current_year_latest_reading_date

        ,(lryps.current_reading_year - 1)                   AS prev_reading_year
        ,(lyrr.latest_reading_date_of_yr - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS prev_year_latest_reading_date

    FROM
        available_stores AS avs

    LEFT JOIN
        current_reading_yr_per_store AS lryps
        ON (lryps.store_name = avs.store_name)

    LEFT JOIN
        latest_reading_ranges_per_year AS lyrr
        ON (lyrr.store_name = avs.store_name)
        AND (lyrr.reading_year = lryps.current_reading_year)
)

--at this stage, we should have all the calculations we need to 
--establish the range for the latest year, and the range for the year prior to that

,current_year_consumption AS
(
    SELECT
        avs.store_name
        SUM(cyed.reading_kwh) AS latest_year_kwh

    FROM
        available_stores AS avs

    LEFT JOIN
        store_reading_ranges AS srs
        ON (srs.store_name = avs.store_name)

    LEFT JOIN
        energy_data_ext AS cyed
        ON (cyed.reading_year = srs.current_reading_year)
        AND (cyed.reading_date <= srs.current_year_latest_reading_date)

    GROUP BY
        avs.store_name
)

,prev_year_consumption AS
(
    SELECT
        avs.store_name
        SUM(pyed.reading_kwh) AS prev_year_kwh

    FROM
        available_stores AS avs

    LEFT JOIN
        store_reading_ranges AS srs
        ON (srs.store_name = avs.store_name)

    LEFT JOIN
        energy_data_ext AS pyed
        ON (pyed.reading_year = srs.prev_reading_year)
        AND (pyed.reading_date <= srs.prev_year_latest_reading_date)

    GROUP BY
        avs.store_name
)

SELECT
    avs.store_name

    ,srs.current_reading_year
    ,srs.current_year_latest_reading_date
    ,lyc.latest_year_kwh

    ,srs.prev_reading_year
    ,srs.prev_year_latest_reading_date
    ,pyc.prev_year_kwh

FROM
    available_stores AS avs

LEFT JOIN
    store_reading_ranges AS srs
    ON (srs.store_name = avs.store_name)

LEFT JOIN
    current_year_consumption AS lyc
    ON (lyc.store_name = avs.store_name)

LEFT JOIN
    prev_year_consumption AS pyc
    ON (pyc.store_name = avs.store_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your note. I have hourly energy consumption data (from energy meters), and the data is fairly clean for all the stores. Thus, getting sums for separate stores current year versus last year gives me a correct pictures of the energy. Here the challenge is that in the current year the stores have different last dates, thus have to find those dates first and sum previous year your for the same intervals. I think there should be an uncomplicated SQL solutions, just my skills are not there...

Comment: @Alexander, so the data is already in *hourly* form (without gaps)? If the data is already very fine-grained, this should be an easy problem to solve. When you say the stores have "different last dates", do you mean not all of the data from all stores is up-to-date (i.e. there could be a gap between the present date and the last recorded consumption)?

Comment: yes, the data is in hourly form (a couple of small gaps have been handles with imputation). And yes, not all the data is "up to date", and probably never will as the data is delivered from different sources. and not always "on time". This, store A have data between 1.1.2018 and 20.01.2018, and store B from 1.1.2018 and 28.01.2018. Need to pull out those dates (as I have in my first SQL statement above) and then sum the same intervals for previous year

Comment: @Alexander, I see, so just to be clear, you want to define a period (which may be anything up to the current date), and then look back one year for the same period? And, if the defined period covers a period for which data is not available, then shorten the period to include only the period for which data is available. So for store A, if the defined period was between 1-Jan-2018 and 11-Feb-2018, that would be abridged to mean the 1-Jan-2018 to 20-Jan-2017, and we would then look back for the data between 1-Jan and 20-Jan-2017 for comparison?.

Comment: Not sure if I explained it well. If store A has data for the intervall between 1.1.2018 - 28.01.2018 I want the sum for that period, and the sum for the same period one year ago (1.1.2017 - 28.01.2017). Then store B I may only have data for 1.1.2018 - 20.1.2018, I get the sum for that period, and compare that with 1.1.2017 and 1.20.2017. I have hundreds of stores. For each of them I sum so far this year (current year), and compare with last year. Ive got the data, but not the SQL to do it.